# soil that is dried (no pore space) weight?

Tags: soil, soil-moisture, soil-science

How much would 1 m3 of an ideal mineral SOIL that has been completely dried (all pore space is empty) weigh in Mg on Earth?  Answer = ______ Mg

Comment: I am confused if I just calculate m or Mg or if it more complicated due to the fact that there is no pore space

Comment: I don't know how you would calculate this because the pores, now empty of all moisture, vary based on the size and shape, and development, of the mineral soil.

Comment: I think this is just based on a generalized particle density

Comment: Just to be clear I am not a soil scientist but how do you generalize the particle density.  I am thinking that the mineral soil component of various types of soils would have vastly different pore sizes.  Clay based soil would have a much higher density than a colluvium based soil.  Again I am likely missing something from the question.

Comment: I think in this case, "ideal" soil density is 2.65 g/cm^3

Comment: Depends on composition. sandy soil composed of mainly quartz will have a near 2.65 g/cm^3 but clayey soils will be considerably more dense.

Comment: Degree of compaction will also significantly change the "answer".